# Web Client DownloadString coming up blank for PHP output

Tags: c#, php

Alright so I have a php script that returns the contents of a SQL table and echos them, when I load the page it works fine however when I download the string via C# it comes up empty... If I output something besides the results of the SQL table it also works.

I've tried WebRequests as well with no luck.

Why could it be not working?

Also the output is just a single line.

Here's my PHP code

```
<?php  
$database="example";  
mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", " ");  
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");  
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM names" )  
or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());  
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);  


while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result)){  
foreach ($get_info as $field)  
echo $field;  
}  

?>
```

C# Code

```
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.3/list.php");
        myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
        myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(responseString);
        }
```

Here is the produced HTML (it's nonsense but I was just testing)

```
jacobsharkeypetergriffinTimPalmer123testlion ofnarnia
```

The weird thing is for example in the php script if i change "$field" to something like "test" it works perfectly and outputs test by the number of table results there are

Comment: tried setting allowredirect to true?

Comment: Just tried it, no luck. I'll post my php script and C# code

Comment: Can we see the HTML that "list.php" produces?

Comment: Why are you using that IP address?

Comment: It's internal at the moment, but it's not the address that's broken. Read the append I just made.. Something is screwy with the PHP. Or maybe could the internal IP be taking to long to output? It works quick when I navigate in browser.

Comment: If they're both on your machine, why don't you use Fiddler or WireShark to capture the communications and see what's going on? And doesn't `localhost` work? I've just never seen anyone use that IP address to ping a website before.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That was going to be my next suggestion. If you want a light sniffer, get SmartSniff at http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html and perhaps you will see what's going on.

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion, and it's not actually localhost it's on another server but it's an internal server. That's just the Local IP. I suspect at this point it's probably related to that so I'll just try it on a normal external IP. If that doesn't work I'll take a look on wireshark. I appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the HTML, it is much less code and a maybe a bit cleaner.

```
string str = string.Empty;

WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Hmm.. When I try to use str it's still blank. Maybe it has something to do with me using the internal IP afterall idunno. Its weird, it works fine in browser.